# Цикл в обратном порядке

Tags: алгоритм, c++

Как его реализовать?)
Еще ламер )

Comment: а Вы знаете, как реализовать цикл в прямом порядке?

Comment: Да но обратный не практиковал ))

Comment: Кошмар...а гуглить не пробовали???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 for(int i = 100;i>=0;i--)
 {
 // работа
 }
```

Comment: В условии можно просто i оставить, только цикл до 1 будет идти в таком случае :)

Answer (score 3):

Хочу предостеречь от возможного неприятного бага при использовании беззнакового счётчика цикла. Если изменить вышеприведённый пример так:

```
for(unsigned int i=100; i>=0; i--)
{
    //работа
}
```

то декремент при i=0 приведёт к тому, что i станет равным 2^32-1 (4 миллиардам с лишним) из-за "недополнения" (переполнения наоборот). А это число больше нуля. Поэтому такой цикл будет бесконечным.